# Salesforce Lightning creating a destroy method to destroy an expense

Tags: apex, controller, lightning

so I am fairly new to lightning and APEX - however I like to throw myself in the deep end of things because it makes me research and find out new aspects.

However with this destroy function I have been struggling to complete it, I am going to try to go into depth as I have asked this twice already but I still have not managed to do it(this is either to me being tired, my own stupidity or the people that did help not responding back - possibly all three), however here it goes.

A little while ago I posted the same question but got no where except making a method in the controller for my list, which called the helper action which called the main expense controller method to destroy the expense I had selected.

Here is the following code for this:

List Helper:

```
({
destroyExpense : function(component) {
var action = component.get("v.dltexpense");

action.setParams({
    expense  : component.get("v.expense")
});

action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.contact", a.getReturnValue());
    } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
        $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
    }
});

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
})
```

List Controller:

```
({
    update : function(component, evt, helper) {
        var expense = component.get("v.expense");
        var updateEvent = component.getEvent("updateExpense");
        updateEvent.setParams({ "expense": expense}).fire();
    },

    destroy : function(component, evt, helper) {
        var expense = component.get("v.expense");
        helper.destroyExpense(component);
    },
})
```

The main ExpenseController for the application:

```
public with sharing class ExpenseController {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Expense__c> getExpenses() {     
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Amount__c, Client__c, Date__c,
        Reimbursed__c, CreatedDate FROM Expense__c];
    }
@AuraEnabled
    public static Expense__c saveExpense(Expense__c expense) {
        upsert expense;
        return expense;
    }
@AuraEnabled
    public static boolean dltexpense(List<Expense__c> expenseList) {
        delete expenseList;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above code is currently the code I am using, however it returns the following error:

> Uncaught error in markup://ui:click : Cannot read property 'setParams'
>   of undefined

Before I was given this code I just had an empty method which obviously didn't do anything so this is all my most recent code. I believe I have the code laid out properly, I have a checkbox that you click on, which calls the List controller - this one calls the List Helper method and then calls the method 'dltexpense' in the main Expensecontroller.

I was wondering if anybody could help me solve this issue and thank you - feel free to comment if I need to add any more code to help.

Comment: Why dltexpense not annotated by @AuraEnabled?

Comment: var action = component.get("v.dltexpense"); => var action = component.get("c.dltexpense");

Comment: I have corrected this now - however forgot to update here, this still does not solve anything though.

Comment: I have also just done this but I am getting a different error now: **Uncaught error in $A.run() : Unable to find 'delete' on 'compound://c.NLExpList'.** @RasMisha

Comment: may be your component have {!c.delete} binding, but must {!c.destroyExpense}

Comment: hmmm I still get the same error for 'destroyExpense' too

Comment: Sorry, method in your controller called *destroy* (not  destroyExpense), you have to bind to {!c.destroy}

Comment: Yep I have just done that :) - I just checked that as well. I am getting the following error: **Uncaught error in $A.run() : Cannot read property 'setParams' of null** any idea what is causing this?

Comment: are you that you change component.get("**v**.dltexpense"); to  component.get("**c**.dltexpense"); for action variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34865/discussion-between-stormviper-and-rasmisha).

Comment: can you also post your component code also